# Installing RcppEigen on amazon ec2

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, rcpp

I tried to install [RcppEigen](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppEigen/index.html) on amazon EC2 (on a t1.micro to 
 make sure It works) & ubuntu 13.04. I tried with both R version was 2.15.2 and 3.0, 32bit ubuntu and 64bit ubuntu. Any time I got the following:

```
root@ip-10-224-4-239:/home/ubuntu# R CMD INSTALL RcppEigen_0.3.1.2.1.tar.gz
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘RcppEigen’ ...
** package ‘RcppEigen’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -O2 -pipe -g  -c RcppEigen.cpp -o RcppEigen.o
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -O2 -pipe -g  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.7/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make: *** [fastLm.o] Error 4
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppEigen’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RcppEigen’
```

Anyone has an idea on how to get RcppEigen to run on EC2?
(Rcpp installs flawlessly....)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That looks like a "simple" out of memory issue.

C++ can be demanding as is, and complex template code (which Eigen surely is) demands even more resources.  Simply try allocating more memory -- otherwise it is hard to kill `g++`.

Comment: Glad to hear!  I think that came up before. Maybe I should add it to the FAQ for Rcpp...

Comment: Great. Years later, I had the same problem when installing package `readr`. Your solution worked too

Comment: Depending on the Linux distribution you use, you often also get binaries made either in the distribution or as eg for Ubuntu via PPAs.  And installing a prebuilt binary takes even less memory :)